# How to handle two setState methods to be executed one after other in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following handleSubmit method, which sets the state and has a call back function to dispatch an action.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        passenger: {
          ...this.state.passenger,
          flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber
        }
      },
      () =>
        this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger))
    );
```

I want to set all the state properties to empty after dispatching the action. If I call setState again as follows in handleSubmit method above, I am getting some issues, mostly because of the Asynchronous behavior or setState.

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        passenger: {
          ...this.state.passenger,
          flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber
        }
      },
      () =>
        this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger))
    );
      this.setState(({ passenger }) => ({
        passenger: {
          ...passenger,
          flightNumber: "",
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
          address: "",
          dob: "",
          passportNumber: ""
        }
      }));
   };
```

I am new to ReactJS and JS. How can I handle this? Is there a way to pass another call back method? Or any other way?

Comment: Can you  explain little more about the issue you are facing ?

Comment: While T.J. Crowder's solution would work, there's not really much point setting the state, then immediately wiping it. Might as well not bother with first `setState`, just do the dispatch first then wipe the state after

Comment: @Jayce444 - Good point. It makes sense to either not bother with the first `setState`, or make the second one wait until the action is *complete* (provided the component shows the flight number next to the passenger or something). And it probably makes sense to wait until the action is complete anyway, since actions can fail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, [Jayce444's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486965/how-to-handle-two-setstate-methods-to-be-executed-one-after-other-in-reactjs/60487026#comment107004957_60486965) is worth noting. The reason for setting state is to update what the component shows. You'll be showing the flight number **very** briefly before wiping the passenger information out entirely. So I'd either not bother with the first `setState`, or make the second one wait until the action has been *completed* (which means `dispatch` would need to return a promise or accept a callback). Waiting for the action to complete would also make sense for another reason: Actions can fail. Clearing the passenger information and then having the operation fail isn't likely to be ideal... :-)

But answering the question:

> I want to set all the state properties to empty after dispatching the action.

In your attempt, you're calling `setState` immediately after having called `setState`, without waiting for the action to be dispatched. Instead, call `setState` within the previous `setState`'s completion callback, after dispatching the action:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState(
    {
      passenger: {
        ...this.state.passenger,
        flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber
      }
    },
    () => {
      this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger))
      this.setState(({ passenger }) => ({
        passenger: {
          ...passenger,
          flightNumber: "",
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
          address: "",
          dob: "",
          passportNumber: ""
        }
      }));
    }
  );
};
```

If the `dispatch` can fail, be sure to only call `setState` to clear the fields on success.

---

Side note: If the goal of the second call is to clear all the passenger fields, you don't need to spread out the previous passenger object and you don't need the callback form of `setState`:

```
this.setState({
  passenger: {
    flightNumber: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    address: "",
    dob: "",
    passportNumber: ""
  }
});
```

---

Side note 2: Repeating field names like that is error-prone, You might want to use a class instead:

```
class Passenger {
    constructor() {
        this.flightNumber = "";
        this.firstName = "";
        this.lastName = "";
        this.address = "";
        this.dob = "";
        this.passportNumber = "";
    }
}
```

Then:

```
this.setState({passenger: new Passenger()});
```

Comment: Getting error for using this inside the callback method - this: this
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan - You must not have copied it correctly. The version in the answer has no syntax errors.

Comment: My bad. It is working fine. Thank you buddy. Your answer gave me a clear picture.

Comment: @T J Crowder,  your latest edit pointing out on the first setState, I am doing that because of the poor design of the project. Basically I am hard coding the data into redux store directly for learning purpose. There is no mapping between Flight and Passenger. That is the reason I am getting flightNumber from URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
this.setState({yourState},()=>{
     this.setState({againUpdateState});
});
```